# AppFabric Testing - How do I know SharePoint is utilising it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, share, app-fabric

AppFabric had a status of DOWN however I was still able to view SharePoint pages etc (though had lots of errors in events viewer). I now have AppFabric UP (In windows services Application Fabric is also running) and wanted to know if SharePoint is making use of it. How can I check this as when it was DOWN SharePoint still appeared to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write something in the News Feed on your My Site and see if it is correctly saved. The aggregation of News feed items (outside of team sites) is powered by distributed cache.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of indications whether DC is working or not?

- If DC is not working then user will face the issue with authentication, Users will get access denied, unexpected errors.
- News Feed is not syncing properly or saving the feed data.
- User can see long wait time for page load, image dropped or time out issues.
- Most of social features  either stop working or throwing errors with correlation id.

Here is good guide to validate the DC: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filipbosmans/2015/09/07/how-to-check-for-issues-with-distributed-cache-and-the-script/